# Why parameter callback from $.post isn't accurate

Tags: jquery

I create button with many task such as create info and send it via $.post method and 
I have to check while data is exist in my database and it's succesfull but while I click the previous parameter is still exist, how to set it to be default..

Please, I need help
thanks a ton

```
cek_data();
if(cek == "NOK"){
    alert("Exist");
}else{
    alert("Data isn't Exist");
}

function cek_data(){
   //statement to store url and data
   $.post( url, data ,
   function(data) {
      cek= data;
   });
}
```

I use die("NOK") to destination PHP file...
and I implement to button on click function...

Comment: Can you provide a full, stand-alone example showing the problem?

Comment: i just wanna check callback data for use to if conditional statement but data is not precision, i have to click 2 times to get result who i want

Comment: as alternate I use $.ajax to check it... use onSuccess and call function check it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not too sure what you are asking I will guess.  You want to call cek_data() and return a value into cek?  I would just use the [$.ajax call with async set to false.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  In the success function set cek=data.  dont do cek= cek_data();, just do cek_data();

Comment: @drachenstern - funny... SJAX.  The reason for the async = false is because he wants to set the value of cek, but I expect he wants it set when he makes the call.  If you leave it async the value will be set when the call finishes but may not complete in time for the value to be used in the instance it is needed.

Comment: @JokoWandiro ~ Sorry for not noticing this sooner, if you'll put an @ before the users-name (as I have done here and as CrazyDart did above me), then they will notice the response and come back to converse with you. SJAX was a joke, since AJAX stands for Asynchronous, and the solution implied is Synchronous, I was just making a joke based on the language. @CrazyDart ~ Yeah, I just wanted to get in a funny, but I understood the blocking nature of the request.

Answer (score 0):

I can hardly understand your code, but I think you want something like this:

```
if (update === true) {
    $(".name" + id.val()).text(name.val());
    operasi_cat = "update";
    cat_id = cat_id;
    hint = "Data sudah di-Update";
    kirim();
} else {
    cek_data();
}


function cek_data() {
  //statement to store url and data
  $.post(url, data, function(data) {
     if (cek !== "NOK") {
        //statement to append data into div element
        kirim();
     } else {
       //statement to tell data is exist
     }
  });
}
```